# Do variables that were declared outside of React component being re-initialize when component re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have something in React like this :

```
let initialRender = true

function App(props){...
  initialRender = false;
...
}
```

When the `App` component being re-render (by changing it's props or state), will the `initialRender` be re-initialize to `true`?

Answer (score 4):

No it will not.
The re-render only affects what's inside the component.